# Services available on Eclipse port 51235

Tags: eclipse, firefox, integration, opera

We use Crucible/FishEye for code reviews and in Firefox there is an Eclipse-icon above the content-view of a source file. If I click it that source file is opened in Eclipse.

Crucible/FishEye doesn't show that icon in Opera. I tried to hack it into Opera just see if it works. However, it doesn't even show the icon:

```html
<img src="http://localhost:51235/icon">
```

`netstat` shows that Eclipse listens on that port and other colleagues are also able to use that extended functionality in Firefox through port 51235, so the port seems to be a predefined port in Eclipse.

1. <strike>Does anyone know how to make that work or what Eclipse checks here?</strike>
2. Does anyone know what's possible through port 51235?

EDIT: I put all findings in my answer

Comment: I do not see it in Chromium either.  Shows up in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That port seems to be part of the [Atlassian](http://www.atlassian.com/)-connector in Eclipse. They wrote [the source](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/connector-eclipse/src/b26692bd1c5d8eb7fc4e01cf94d731874c25a49a/com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.directclickthrough.ui/src/com/atlassian/connector/eclipse/internal/directclickthrough/servlet/DirectClickThroughServlet.java?at=default) and a [test class for their connector](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/connector-eclipse/src/77f70dee2ea7/com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.tests/src/HttpServerTest.html).

Here's a brief list of possible URLs:

- Icon: `http://localhost:51235/icon`
- Open an issue: `http://localhost:51235/issue?issue_key=PL-31&server_url=https://studio.atlassian.com/&id=`
- Open a build: `http://localhost:51235/build?build_key=ECL-COM&build_number=1118&server_url=https://gdansk.bamboo2.atlassian.com&id=`
- Open a file:

  - `http://localhost:51235/file?file=plugin.xml&id=`
  - `http://localhost:51235/file?file=org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.core/plugin.xml&id=`
  - `http://localhost:51235/file?file=CompletionActionStates.java&path=src/org/dubik/codecompletionlive/completions&line=10&id=`
  - `http://localhost:51235/file?file=Test.java&path=src/main/java/com/atlassian/connector&line=10&vcs_root=https://studio.atlassian.com/svn/PL/trunk/atlassian-intellij-connector/&id=`
- Open a review

  - file and versioned comment defined: `http://localhost:51235/review?review_key=CR-PL-66&server_url=https://svn.atlassian.com/atlaseye&file_path=src/main/java/com/atlassian/theplugin/util/CodeNavigationUtil.java&comment_id=CMT:9831&id=`
  - file defined: `http://localhost:51235/review?review_key=CR-PL-66&server_url=https://svn.atlassian.com/atlaseye&file_path=src/main/java/com/atlassian/theplugin/util/CodeNavigationUtil.java&id=`
  - general comment defined: `http://localhost:51235/review?review_key=CR-PL-66&server_url=https://svn.atlassian.com/atlaseye&comment_id=CMT:9899&id=`

**Note:**

- `id` is always filled with `Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)`, i.e. a random number between 0 and 999
- all links return the icon

Answer (score 0):

If you add an IFRAME loading that URL, you may see a cross-network error page. If you do, opt in to always allow the traffic for that server, and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. There is something completely odd happening. If I write the URL or the one that supposedly opens a source file in Eclipse in Opera's address bar, it works nicely. I see Eclipse' icon. I guess I have to dig more into the JavaScript-code of Crucible/FishEye. I'm scraping off my question 1.

Comment: Sorry that I was brief. See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464599/opera-wont-load-some-javascript-files/7442998#7442998